# How to edit content in a .phar file?

Tags: php, phar

In my case, the phar file is used to translate an internet page in another language

I have to update a translation, for example:

```
  'Open a New Ticket' => 'old_phrase'
   to
  'Open a New Ticket' => 'new_phrase'
```

If I do so by editing the file with a text editor the file is no longer recognized by the system, so I guess I have to use the php `Phar` class, but I don't know if there's a function to change an existing file in the phar.

Any suggestions / solutions ?

Comment: Edit the original source files, and then rebuild the phar

Comment: what do u mean with rebuild the phar exactly?

Comment: Typically you will have a script that bundles the source files into a phar, ie that builds it

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Phar::offsetSet()`](http://php.net/phar.offsetset) to change the data of a phar, if you already have the Phar object:

```
$phar = new Phar("phar.phar");
$phar["entry.php"] .= 'echo "Modified!\n";'
```

Or use file_put_contents() with the phar scheme:

```
file_put_contents("phar:///path/to/phar.phar/entry.php", 'echo "Modified!\n";', FILE_APPEND);
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy:
(https://phar.scer.io/)

-Convert phar to zip.

-Extract and edit.

-Zip and convert zip to phar.